# Extract high and low data from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is the data_frame That I am working on

```
 -      Date     Open    High    Low   Close
1. 01-08-2019 | 97.85 | 98.45 | 96.40 |97.25
2. 02-08-2019 | 97.15 | 98.95 | 96.75 |98.15
3. 05-08-2019 | 98.30 | 98.70 | 94.30 |95.65
4. 06-08-2019 | 95.75 | 97.75 | 95.20 |97.05
5. 07-08-2019 | 96.80 | 97.70 | 96.05 |96.90
- ................
```

After running below code:

```
new=data_frame.groupby(data_frame.index // 2).agg({'Date': 'last','High':'max','Low':'min'})
```

The result obtained was below DataFrame;

```
      Date      High    Low
0   02-08-2019  98.95   96.40
1   06-08-2019  98.70   94.30
2   08-08-2019  98.90   96.05
3   12-08-2019  98.10   93.40
4   14-08-2019  96.60   93.15
```

I want to to take two days high low and store it on the third day. For example, 01-08-2019 and 02-08-2019 high and low should be compared stored on 3rd day ie 05-08-2019. similarly, 02-08-2019 and 05-08-2019 should be compared to find high low and store it on the third day ie 06-08-2019. 05-08-2019 and 06-08-2019 should be compared to find high low and store it on the third day ie 07-08-2019.

Expected data frame from my above explanation is as follows:

```
       Date      High    Low
0   05-08-2019  98.95   96.40
1   06-08-2019  98.95   94.30
2   07-08-2019  98.70   94.30
```

[Link to data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OzRUHDMwh6xEp2ajdq3-rI5ddseGLhbV/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can you below code

```
x1=[]
x2=[]
x3=[]
count=0
date=data_frame['Date'].tolist()
high=data_frame['High'].tolist()
low=data_frame['Low'].tolist()
high.pop()
low.pop()
for i in range (len(data_frame)-2):

    if count==0:
        temp=pd.DataFrame()
        date.remove(date[0])
        temp['Date']=date
        temp['High']=high
        temp['Low']=low
        count=1
    else:
        temp=pd.DataFrame()
        date.remove(date[0])
        temp['Date']=date
        high.remove(high[0])
        low.remove(low[0])
        temp['High']=high
        temp['Low']=low
        
    TwoDay_High_Low=temp.groupby(temp.index // 2).agg({'Date': 'last','High':'max','Low':'min'})
    x1.append(TwoDay_High_Low['Date'].iloc[0])
    x2.append(TwoDay_High_Low['High'].iloc[0])
    x3.append(TwoDay_High_Low['Low'].iloc[0])
```

finally making a dataframe to store extraced data

```
two_day=pd.DataFrame()
two_day['Date']=x1
two_day['High']=x2
two_day['Low']=x3
two_day
```